# Execute same query for multiple tables in a database

Tags: sql

I have  51 tables (in a single DB) having same column and schema for 51 USA states. All i have to do is to run the same query for all 51 tables. The result of each state should return in to new table with a tableformat like this.

```
Eg. Table name : TX_EED
    New Table name :TX_EED_v0
```

**Following is the query which i will run for each state:**

```
Select distinct a.Geoid, Lat, Long, StateCode, CountyCode, PostalCode,StrVal_SFD ,StrVal_MFD,StrVal_MH from EED2013..TX_EED a
inner join 
(Select Geoid,
SUM(case when LOBNAME ='SFD'THEN CvgAval_MinThresh else 0 end) as StrVal_SFD,
SUM(case when LOBNAME ='MFD'THEN CvgAval_MinThresh else 0 end) as StrVal_MFD,
SUM(case when LOBNAME ='MH'THEN CvgAval_MinThresh else 0 end) as StrVal_MH
FROM EED2013..TX_EED group by Geoid) b
on a.Geoid =b.Geoid-------7,473,869
```

Comment: The real question is: Why do you have 51 tables instead of one table with a field that indicates the state?

Comment: +1 Thorsten, however sometimes its out of your control, database was made before you had any input...however, I am not sure what the question is here... He knows what he has to do...

Answer (score 2):

If you have 51 tables with the same schema, then you should really have a single table.  By the way, there are more than "51" state-equivalents in the US -- DC, Puerto Rico, Guam, US Virgin Islands, and various military addresses count as "states" according to the US Post Office (and I think the US Census).

In any case, create a view:

```
create view v_AllStates as
    select ak.*
    from data_al union all
    select al.*
    from data_al union all
    . . .
    select wy.*
    from data_wy;
```

You can then use this view in your queries, presumably simplifying your life.

Comment: ...which would allow him to then switch everything over to using this view (over time), allowing him to create a new table (.... ideally with the same name...) with the same data, then just removing the old tables.